# Calling JavaScript functions via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a PHP file which have variables collected from HTML. I have also a JavaScript function.

I want to call the JavaScript function via PHP but I know it's impossible because the PHP code is before the JavaScript code.

I put it before the JS code because JavaScript collects variables from the PHP code only when the PHP is before the JavaScript file.

How can I call the JS function from PHP and still have the variables? (By echo 'after();'

This is my index.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['secondName']))
{
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $secondName = $_REQUEST['secondName'];
    echo '<script>after();</script>';
}
else
{
    $name = '';
    $secondName = '';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function after()
    {
    var name = '<?=$name?>';
    var secondName = '<?=$secondName?>';
    var str = "         ";
    if(!str.replace(/\s/g, '').length)
    {
        alert("error");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#pre-text").fadeIn();
        $("#text").html(fullName);
        $("#pre-text").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    }   
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get">
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>Second name: <input type="text" name="secondName"> <input type="submit"></p>
<p id="pre-text" style="display:none">Your first name is: <span id="text"></span>. You can also click me to hide.</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help.

EDIT: I want to call the function after().

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue? PHP will be executed before JS, so the JS function won't even be executed after all of the php is done.

Comment: PHP doesn't (ever) call JavaScript. It only serves the HTML files that contain the JavaScript calls. The browser receives the file then executes the JavaScript.

Comment: I mean by "echo"ing '<script>after();</script>';

Comment: What's you want actually? You simply want the PHP variables data to the your javascript function right ?

Comment: Check my answer. I feel it will perfect for you and will work as you want. @shabenda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo '<script>after();</script>';
```

with

```
$hasData = true;
```

Then you can do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <?=isset($hasData) && $hasData === true ? 'after();' : ''?>
});
```

Also, you'll receive a javascript error as 'fullName' isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I looked for. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You out your after() function in $(document).ready block. So you will can not call it like that. So I think you should do this

Change

```
echo '<script>after();</script>';
```

To

```
echo '<script>$(document).ready(function(){after()};</script>';
```

And change

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function after()
    {
    var name = '<?=$name?>';
    var secondName = '<?=$secondName?>';
    var str = "         ";
    if(!str.replace(/\s/g, '').length)
    {
        alert("error");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#pre-text").fadeIn();
        $("#text").html(fullName);
        $("#pre-text").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    }   
    }
});
</script>
```

to

```
<script>
    function after()
    {
    var name = '<?=$name?>';
    var secondName = '<?=$secondName?>';
    var str = "         ";
    if(!str.replace(/\s/g, '').length)
    {
        alert("error");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#pre-text").fadeIn();
        $("#text").html(fullName);
        $("#pre-text").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    }   
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the script section, you can use PHP code to run the function *after()*

```
<script>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['secondName']))
{
    echo '<script>after();</script>';
}
?>
//more js code
</script>
```

PHP is basically putting your own code in HTML just before it is outputted. So, based on your conditions, use PHP blocks to print what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `PHP` variables data to the `JavaScript` and worked on it, so there is no need to call the `JavaScript` function from the `PHP`

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['secondName']))
{
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $secondName = $_REQUEST['secondName'];
}
else
{
    $name = '';
    $secondName = '';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';
    var secondName = '<?php echo $secondName; ?>';
    var str = "         ";
    if(!str.replace(/\s/g, '').length)
    {
        alert("error");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#pre-text").fadeIn();
        $("#text").html(fullName);
        $("#pre-text").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    }   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get">
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
<p>Second name: <input type="text" name="secondName"> <input type="submit"></p>
<p id="pre-text" style="display:none">Your first name is: <span id="text"></span>. You can also click me to hide.</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Try this code I am sure it works for you.